# An optimal way of getting a correct reshape of that dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've the following dataframe:

```
df = 
    c   f   V   E
0   M   5  32  22
1   M   7  45  40
2   R   7  42  36
3   R   9  41  38
4   R   3  28  24
```

And I want a result like this, in which the values ​​of column 'f' are my new columns, and my new indexes are a combination of column 'c' and the rest of columns in the dataframe (the order of rows doesn't matter):

```
df_result = 
        3   5    7    9
 V(M) NaN  32   45  NaN
 E(M) NaN  22   40  NaN
 V(R) 28  NaN   42   41
 E(R) 24  NaN   36   38
```

Currently, my code is:

```
df_result = pd.concat([df.pivot('c','f',col).rename(index = {e: col + '(' + e + ')' for e in df.pivot('c','f',col).index}) for col in [e for e in df.columns if e not in ['c','f']]])
```

With that code I'm getting:

```
df_result = 
f      3   5   7   9
c
E(M)  NaN  22  40  NaN
E(R)   24 NaN  36   38
V(M)  NaN  32  45  NaN
V(R)   28 NaN  42   41
```

I think it's a valid result, however, I don't know if there is a way to get exactly my desire result or, at least, a better way to get what I am already getting.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the table, this is `.melt` + `.pivot_table`

```
df_result = df.melt(['f', 'c']).pivot_table(index=['variable', 'c'], columns='f')
```

Then we can clean up the naming:

```
df_result = df_result.rename_axis([None, None], 1)
df_result.columns = [y for _,y in df_result.columns]

df_result.index = [f'{x}({y})' for x,y in df_result.index]
# Python 2.:      ['{0}({1})'.format(*x) for x in df_result.index]
```

## Output:

```
         3     5     7     9
E(M)   NaN  22.0  40.0   NaN
E(R)  24.0   NaN  36.0  38.0
V(M)   NaN  32.0  45.0   NaN
V(R)  28.0   NaN  42.0  41.0
```

You might consider keeping the MultiIndex instead of flattening to new strings, as it can be simpler for certain aggregations.

Comment: You are right about your multiIndex advice, but I need it in this way. About your code: I'm getting a SyntaxError in `f'{x}({y})' `

Comment: @Á.Garzón which python are you using? Does `['{0}({1})'.format(*x) for x in df_result.index]` resolve it?

Comment: Great. f-strings are a python 3 feature, so need to use the old formatting syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `pivot_table`

```
s=pd.pivot_table(df,index='c',columns='f',values=['V','E']).stack(level=0).sort_index(level=1)
s.index=s.index.map('{0[1]}({0[0]})'.format)
s
Out[95]: 
f        3     5     7     9
E(M)   NaN  22.0  40.0   NaN
E(R)  24.0   NaN  36.0  38.0
V(M)   NaN  32.0  45.0   NaN
V(R)  28.0   NaN  42.0  41.0
```